# Directory and files not showing up in QtCreator tree after opening a CMakeList.txt file

Tags: cmake

I apologize for the basic question but being new to Cmake, I have a hard time doing very simple things.

So basically, I'm working on the pixhawk firmware : https://github.com/PX4/Firmware which uses extensively CMake/make files.

Under the `src` folder, I've created my own folder containing two subfolders which contain themselves their CMakeLists.txt file and the source code (no CMakeLists.txt in my own folder).

However, when I open the top CMakeLists.txt in QtCreator, my own newly created folder (along with its sub-folder and containing files) doesn't appear in the tree, which is very inconvenient to work directly from QtCreator.

What should I modify in the top CMakeLists.txt to get it display in QtCreator ? I thought that a simple include_subdirectory would do the job but it didn't (because, if my memory's right, cmake was complaining that there is no CMakeLists.txt in my own folder, only in its sub-folders).

Ps : if by any chance, you're a drone developer and know about pixhawk, it would be very nice if you could take some time to answer the questions I posted there : http://discuss.px4.io/t/cmake-help/4523

Answer (score 0):

Hum maybe you can simply add this to your top CmakeList ?

```
add_subdirectory(myfolder/app1)
add_subdirectory(myfolder/app2)
```

Comment: It's going to be quite unpractical when there will be a lot of subdirectories, don't you think so ? Moreover, I dont see anything of that kind in the CMakeLists.txt file that's already present, yet all the subfolders in src are shown in Qt Creator (cf the github directory in my previous message)